# Calling functions inside functions when the inner function's arguments will always be the same as the outer's

Tags: ruby, function, methods

The `inner_method` is only ever called within `outer_method`, and its argument will always be identical to `outer_method`'s.

This works:

```
def outer_method(word)
  inner_method(word)
  puts word + " are like candy."
end

def inner_method(same_word)
  puts "I really love " + same_word + "!"
end

outer_method("onions")
```

but this doesn't:

```
def outer_method(word)
  inner_method
  puts word + "tastes like candy."
end

def inner_method
  puts "I really love " + word + "!"
end

outer_method("onions")
```

It seems that `inner_method`'s reference to `word` is not being registered by `outer_method`. Is there a better way to do this?

(I realize there's no reason to have a separate `inner_method` in the above example; this is simplified for clarity's sake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly think your first technique is the best way to go and perfectly idiomatic.  Still, here's another option:

```
def outer_method(word)
  inner_lambda = lambda do
    puts "I really love " + word + "!"
  end

  inner_lambda.call
  puts word + " tastes like candy."
end

outer_method("onions")
```

`lambda` creates a lexical closure, which means it captures the surrounding environment, including the reference to `word`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'm not really hip to lambdas yet. I'll just keep the first technique, though, since it's really not much less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There are two concerns with your question. The shallow one is your learning Ruby syntax. The deeper one is learning proper coding patterns. In your case, *word* object begs to exist:

```
class MyWord < String
  def singular?; @singular end

  def initialize **setup
    singular, plural = setup[:singular], setup[:plural]
    if singular then @singular = true
      super singular
    elsif plural then @singular = false
      super plural
    else fail ArgumentError, "Bad MyWord constructor arguments!" end
  end

  def interjection_1
    "I really love #{self}!"
  end

  def interjection_2
    "#{capitalize} #{singular? ? 'is' : 'are'} like cand#{singular? ? 'y' : 'ies'}!"
  end

  def hysteria
    puts interjection_1
    puts interjection_2
  end
end
```

And then:

```
MyWord.new( plural: "onions" ).hysteria
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. What was wrong with my syntax? Also, can you recommend a book or website that covers "proper coding patterns"?

Comment: @user2493615: Patterns [dates back to before Ruby](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SoftwareDesignPatterns). It's part science, part art. Matz himself has designed Ruby largely on intuition, so don't feel ashamed if you do the same when using it. I am not a theorist either, but I can tell you, if the same concern keeps popping up in the arguments of various methods, it is time to make a class for that concern and make those methods its instance methods. Maybe [this great talk](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/1233-aloharuby2012-refactoring-from-good-to-great) has influenced me, too.